# Set version with AssemblyInfoTask from a file

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm completely new to this MSBuild tool (and still somewhat lost) but nonetheless I have a question someone might be able to answer:

I am trying to auto-generate version info into AssemblyVersion.cs files by the contents of a file.

To set the verion info I found the AssemblyInfoTask which works quite well - but how do I tell that task to set Major, Minor, Build and Revision by the contents of file which could then be used in a series of projects alltogether?

Curious - and thankful for any reply 'cause I'm pulling my hairs here! ;-)

yours,
Florian

Answer (score 3):

You could, instead, use a shared `AssemblyVersion.cs` file in the different projects - if that suits your goal.
To do that, simply add one `AssemblyVersion.cs` to one project, then in the other projects select `Add -> Existing Items...`, select the `AssemblyVersion.cs` file and instad of click `Add` click the arrow next to it and select `Add As Link`.